# does powerbuilder 12.6 support for running text?

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm now using powerbuilder 12.6 for my work, I have been learning powerbuilder for 2 month. Now, to make my powerbuilder product more good looking, I need to add some running text effect. So my question is, does powerbuilder 12.6 support for running text?and how is the code for this running text effect?
Thank you every one :)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't supported but would be relatively easy to build the functionality by creating a visual user object. If you do build the functionality please consider adding it to the PFC Framework for PowerBuilder. The framework can be found on one of the common open source repositories.